# How to set response header in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a method in which i want to set response header cache-control and pragma :-

```
public String addUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        bindingResult.getFieldError();
        return"edit";
    }
    return "redirect:/welcome/profile/"+user.getName();
}
```

In this method i want to set cache-control and pragma like we do in simple servlet code using HttpservletResponse calling setHeader method :-

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

I searched spring docs and could not find any direct way to do it, but I found this:-

```
@RequestMapping("/something")
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
{
    String requestHeader = requestEntity.getHeaders().getFirst("MyRequestHeader"));
    byte[] requestBody = requestEntity.getBody();
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

But I dont know how to use it

Comment: _But I dont know how to use it_ Seems like you are using it fine.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to set headers for every response for a controller you can use `@ModelAttribute` annotation.

```
@ModelAttribute
public void setVaryResponseHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Vary", "Accept");
}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
  public String addUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
  {
       if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
       {
            bindingResult.getFieldError();
            return"edit";
      }
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
      response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
      response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
      return "redirect:/welcome/profile/"+user.getName();
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Spring v. 4.1:

```
@RequestMapping("/something")
public ResponseEntity<MyClass> handle()
{
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
              .header("header", "value")
              .body(new MyClass());
}
```

Comment: how can I set `n` number of headers say from an array or a list?

Comment: You can use ResponseEntity.headers( **HttpHeaders** ).body( ... ).

The class HttpHeaders implements a MultiValueMap<String, String> interface and has methods **addAll(MultiValueMap<K,V> values)** and **addAll(K key, List<? extends V> values)**

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set headers as follows.

imports:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
```

code:

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> doSomething() {
   ...
HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
respHeaders.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
respHeaders.add("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```