# Server responded with a status of 401 - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Angular Js - working fine with Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, spring-security

Client side : **AngularJS**

Server / tech : **Apache / Java Spring**

First error was the No Access Control Allow Origin header not present. We fixed that by adding [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117763/3192693) to the server side. The request is working fine with *postman*.

In Controller function http get method is returning error 401 (Unauthorized).

```
$http.get("our_local_url").then(function(data) {
                console.log("data:"+data);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("error:"+error);
            });
```

A Test page with Jquery Ajax Call is working fine with the code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "our_local_url",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            console.log(error);
        }
});
```

I've gone through several SO answers before asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some security handling in the spring-security which was blocking the call. After it's removed, it worked (No Access Control Allow Origin header added).

Answer (score 0):

Add `withCredentials: true` in service call

try this below

```
$http.get("our_local_url", { withCredentials: true }).then{...};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However trying that code doesn't help. Still showing the same error with angular. working fine with jquery ajax.