# Setting headers in RedirectView in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new in Java, In our application we are using RedirectView for redirecting to particular URL. My question here is there any way by which I can set Headers to this RedirectView Url. As we need to send some data at the redirected Page.
I know its a silly question, I have just started studying Java :)
Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set using `response`. I have taken the example for file attachment.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="",method=RequestMethod.Method)
    public myMethod(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        response.setContentType("application/XXX");         
    }
```

---

You can set the following methods to set response Header

- void setHeader(String name, String value)
- void addDateHeader(String name, long date)
- void addHeader(String name, String value)
- void addIntHeader(String name, int value)
- String encodeRedirectURL(String url)
- String encodeURL(String url)
- void addCookie(Cookie cookie)
  ...

Comment: Thanks for Answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

springboot

```
RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("redirect:/users");
    redirectView.setPropagateQueryParams(true);
    return redirectView;
```

Comment: Ok, But how are you going to Custom Header information in this ?

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/18534478/8747660 and custom with redirectView